# How to prevent data from disappearing on webpage

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I want to prevent my data from disappearing on the webpage whenever I refresh the page.
Please how do I go about that with local storage in JavaScript?

Comment: your question's already been answered, but you seem like a beginner so I should let you know, localStorage works on your browser only, for persistently saving the data everywhere you need to use a server and a database (like PHP)

Answer (score 1):

I would like to suggest resources like  https://www.w3schools.com/

but take a look at this

```
<p>Saved name is:</p>
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
// Set Item
localStorage.setItem("lastname", "Smith");
// Retrieve
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("lastname");
</script>
```

Comment: w3schools  is not the best learning source. While it is not as bad as it used to be it is still full of inaccuracies.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say if you want the user to login after he has logged in the first time on your website then you will use `localStorage`. How to use it?

```
// to add new item to the cache memory of the user
localStorage.setItem('key', //anything here);
//to get it
localStorage.getItem('key');
// to remove it
localStorage.removeItem('key');
// to remove all of it
localStorage.clear();
```